# Pandas with jupyter, how filter a valid email format and excessive length rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a dataframe in which I would like to filter the "email" column by excluding everything in the column that is not an email, example:

```
email;credit;name;data
test1@aol.com;123;lucash;02-07-2021
test2_test@hotmail.com;223;mary;01-07-2021
hshdgdhsj"";324;fabian;29-06-2021
test3lol_@gmail.com;11;scot;20-06-2021
qweryiij;444;giusy;16-06-2021
ted@mail.com;149;ted;11-06-2021;tedted
```

I use pandas and I only need lines starting with a valid email, and lines not exceeding three (3) semicolons (;) like this below:

```
email;credit;name;data
test1@aol.com;123;lucash;02-07-2021
test2_test@hotmail.com;223;mary;01-07-2021
test3lol_@gmail.com;11;scot;20-06-2021
```

is a large file and is open:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv', sep = ';',error_bad_lines=False,encoding='utf8',engine='python')
df
```

do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?
thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `str.extract()`:

```
pat=r'([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)'
df['email']=df['email'].str.extract(pat,expand=False)
df=df.dropna(subset=['email'])
```

**regex explaination:**

Firstly we have character set that matches uppercase words,lowercase words digits,unserscore,period,a plus sign or a hyphen then we have + sign that matches one or more occurance of it untill @:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@
```

For domain we have another character set which matches uppercase words,lowercase words,digits and hyphen followed by + sign that will match 1 or more occurance of it untill it find period(.):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.
```

After that period we have another characterset that will match uppercase words,lowercase words,digits,hyphen and a periodand + sigh that will match 1 or more occurance of it

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+
```

Comment: Thanks ... it seems to work great, even fast in the response !!!! :-)